# Is "please find enclosed the attachment" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, definite-articles

In my office everyone uses "Please find enclosed the attachment" in emails.

I can't digest the "the" between "enclosed" and "attachment". Is the sentence grammatical?

Comment: This question would probably be better suited to our sister site, http://ell.stackexchange.com (English Language Learners).

Comment: Mail or email? In snail mail I prefer the following: "Enclosed is _____________" (fill in the blank); or "Please see the enclosed ____________" (fill in the blank). The word "find" is not needed; this isn't "hide and seek"!  For email, I prefer the following:  "Please read/open the attachments to this email," or something similar.  Again, nix the word "find," as most people know where to look for, and open, email attachments.

Comment: Essentially the same question asked here has been asked again just now about "Please find enclosed the tickets." In both cases the location of the "the" in the phrase seems to be a sticking point for the person posting the question. In any case, particularly after reading Janus Bahs Jacquet's well-informed answer below, I don't see why this isn't a legitimate question for English Language & Usage. I recommend reopening this question.

Comment: @SvenYargs I agree and have voted for it to be. It's also a not easily recognisable case of heavy noun phrase shift. The phrase order here is normally ungrammatical and is only rendered grammatical because of the four syllable direct object. consider *"Please find enclosed it" as opposed to "Please find it enclosed". Thsi question has lots going for it, and would be helpful for readers. And quite apart from that, as Geoff Atwood stated before, it's openable just because it's "interesting for experts" (I consider you and Janus experts) and for general readers.

Answer (score 3):

As both Greg and Colin point out, there is nothing in this sentence that violates any of the grammatical principles English sentences must adhere to. There is, however, something that make it violate certain *semantic* requirements for well-formed sentences.

The definite article has two basic uses (very roughly generalised):

1. It is used to describe certain things that are uniquely named or specified, or to a class of another class. For example, ‘the definite article’ is a unique specification, as it refers not just to any article that happens to be definite (‘a definite article’ works for that), but to the specific grammatical element *the* in the English language.
2. When used with words that are not uniquely specified, it is used *only* when the noun it determines **is defined and identifiable to the listener** in the discourse that is currently taking place. When something has already been established in the context, a definite article may (and in many cases must) be used; if it is introduced to the discourse for the first time and no prior framework for it exists, a definite article *cannot* be used.

Now in your example, “the attachment” is not a uniquely specified thing—there is no specific thing ‘named’ *The Attachment*, so to speak. Therefore, in order to merit the definite article, the discourse/context must already have made it clear what attachment we are talking about. If this has been done, your sentence is fine, but it requires a specific kind of scenario; for example:

> Jane sent me an e-mail with some huge file attached this morning. I don’t know what it was, but something must have been wrong somewhere, ’cause *the attachment* made my entire computer crash when I tried to open it.

When writing an e-mail, though, ‘attachment’ is a very vague word. It tells you that a file of some sort is being sent along, but it does not mention what file it is, nor what is contained in that file. Therefore, a scenario like the above is not very likely—when we receive something as an attachment, we tend to prefer to call the thing we’ve received by its proper name/description, rather than just calling it ‘the attachment’. As such, we rarely find ourselves defining ‘attachment’ in a discourse.

As such, saying merely, “Please find enclosed the attachment” will sound very strange to most people. The immediate reaction is, “What attachment?”—not because we don’t know how to look for an attachment to an e-mail, but because the definite article makes us immediately think that *this is something that should be familiar to me*. If you have not just defined ‘an attachment’ in the previous text, people won’t know what attachment you are talking about.

Of course, changing the wording to using an indefinite article (appropriate when introducing a new thing to the discourse) won’t work either: if you say, “Please find enclosed an attachment”, people are just going to wonder if you do not even know what attachment you are sending along.

The best way to solve this is to tell people what you are sending along. This is, in fact, common practice in English—as Colin’s example amply illustrates.

Also, you should note that ‘enclose’ and ‘attach’ basically mean the same thing. The only difference between them is that ‘attach’ is used only for electronic communication, while ‘enclose’ is used mostly for non-electronic communication (where enclosing something actually means physically *enclosing* it inside the envelope). Using both together is somewhat redundant and unnecessary.

It is therefore more common to write in an e-mail, “Please find attached [something or other]”, rather than, “Please find enclosed [something] as attachment”. So if you are sending an agenda for a meeting, for example, simply write:

> Please find attached the agenda for the meeting.

Answer (score 2):

It is grammatical, but not idiomatic (at least in my idiolect). *Enclosed* is a modifier for the verb phrase, somewhat equivalent to a prepositional phrase (PP) like *on the table* or *in the waste-bin*.

A more normal order would be *Please find the attachment enclosed*; but when the object is a "heavy" phrase, then it is common to put the complement before it, as

> Please find enclosed my response to Mr Smith's email.

Comment: +1 Yes, it's a case , even in the original, of heavy noun phrase shift.  Notice the total weirdness of "*Please find enclosed it*". (Which, of course, must be "*Please find it enclosed*")

Answer (score 2):

The past participle, "enclosed" is actually functioning as an *adverb of condition* to modify "find." You'll find this in poetry a lot. E.g. ". . . find unwithered on its curls" from A. E. Houseman's "To an Athlete Dying Young." It is not just limited to the verb "find." E.g. "They fired unplanned the fatal volley."

The language of letter writing contains many old-fashioned expressions, and this is just one of them. That said, in modern American usage, most of us would just say "Please see the attachment."